# Can't get output of supervisord monitored process

Tags: python, monitoring, supervisord

I created a test executable to see if I could capture the output of a program monitored by Supervisord.

**tester.py:**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import time, os
pid = os.getpid()
print "EXECUTING ON %s" % pid
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    print "HOLLER %s" % pid
```

**supervisord.conf:**

```
[program:mytester]
command={path}/tester.py
```

But when I try to run a `tail` on the process in supervisorctl, nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since you asked, but in case you are still interested and for anyone that has this same problem:

In this case Python is buffering the output and you will not see it until is flushed to stdout. You can force a flush with `sys.stdout.flush()` in your program, but probably the cleanest way of fixing it is to run your script in *unbuffered mode* with the `-u` flag of the Python interpreter:

**supervisord.conf**

```
[program:mytester]
command=python -u {path}/tester.py
```

(Had the same problem and found the solution in supervisord's [mailing list](https://lists.supervisord.org/pipermail/supervisor-users/2008-October/000291.html))

Comment: thanks- I don't have a way to test your answer right now, but seems right!

Comment: in my case all the logs went straight to /tmp - e.g. /tmp/test_python---supervisor-Lt44XR.log. The supervisor would ignore all my efforts in config file to put them elsewhere.

Comment: @patriciasz, so when you execute the program directly -whithout supervisord being involved-, do you get the output to stdout?